# ActiveReports SubReport in a SubReport

Tags: activereports

Can a SubReport in ActiveReports have a SubReport?  I've got a subreport which is not displaying, its inside another SubReport so was wondering if only subReport to a main report is allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating Nested SubReports is possible. You may have a look at the sample working at our end with AR10 : 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/c4o0momxcyko0zn/AR10_NestedSubReportsTest.zip?dl=0

You can download our latest AR10 release from the link below : 
http://activereports.grapecity.com/Downloads/

Also, if the issue still perists, then you are requested to share your application and observations by submitting a ticket here : 
http://activereports.grapecity.com/Support/